# Magento 2.1: Get Breadcrumb Array

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, module, breadcrumbs

How can I get the breadcrumb array from my template?

I'm able to get the object:

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs');
```

and full breadcrumb path as final HTML

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')->toHtml;
```

But when I use getData or toJson it returns the object, not the breadcrumb data.

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')->getData;
```

**Returns**

```
 array(2) { ["type"]=> string(36)
 "Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs" ["module_name"]=> string(13)
 "Magento_Theme" }
```

---

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')->toJson;
```

**Returns**

```
 string(81)
 "{"type":"Magento\\Theme\\Block\\Html\\Breadcrumbs","module_name":"Magento_Theme"}"
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a rather old question, but since I ran into sort of the same issue I thought I'd share my answer:

If you want to call it in a custom template, I suppose you should make a module first and create a custom `Block` class. Then use dependency injection to get the `Helper\Data` from the Magento_Catalog-module, as follows:

```
<?php
namespace Name\Module\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data;

class CustomBreadcrumbBlock {

    protected $catalogData;

    public function __construct(
        Data $catalogData
    ) {
        $this->catalogData = $catalogData;
    }

    public function getBreadcrumbPath() {
        return $this->catalogData->getBreadcrumbPath();
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to call `$block->getBreadcrumbPath()` in your custom block template, which will return an array of your breadcrumb path.

Comment: it will return breadcrumb only on catalog category and product page

Comment: will this work on custom pages as well?

Comment: @VishalParkash I'm not sure. It's been a while since I visited this part of M2. It's worth a try, though. I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: For me it did not work, I think Magento2 reads only the defined pages for custom magento2 breadcrumb does not work. It returns empty array

Answer (score 1):

You can also just extend the Magento\Catalog\Block\Breadcrumbs class when you make your custom block class. To use the getBreadcrumbsPath() method you write a public method to access the protected object $catalogData to use Data::getBreadcrumbsPath() (i.e. getCatalogDataHandler()).

Then in phtml-file you can do like $block->getCatalogDataHandler()->getBreadcrumbsPath().

The getBreadcrumbsPath() method gives you an assoc array with some category id as key and link and label in value-array so perhaps its a good idea anyway to write a public block-method that gives you exactly what you want. I just needed the id for the top level category.

CODE:`$breadcrumbsBlock = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Breadcrumbs');`

Comment: why didn't you post the code instead of writing this much of content?